# IOS - How to handle notification when app is not running

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I tried some ways to handle receive notification when app is not running but nothing works.

Tried with didReceiveRemoteNotification, fetchCompletionHandler, notificationService..

I want to save notification on sqlite when app is not running, how can i do this ?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? if my guess is right, when the app is closed but receive a push notification and the user press on it and the app launches you want to handle what happens, if this is the scenario, then you should you the 'launchOptions' parameter in the appDelegate 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions' method, you can extract from this parameter the same values you get from the notifications methods.

Comment: I want to save notification on sqlite, but using didFinishLaunchingWithOptions my code doesn't executes when the app is not running

Answer (score 1):

iOS won't start the app for you when your push notification arrives and the app is not running. You have to wait for user to start the app or click on your notification.

You could still try to use a **notification content app extension** that will run your code (in somewhat restricted mode - no long running tasks, no network requests etc.) to allow you to customize the look of your notification. For more information see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotificationsui/customizing_the_appearance_of_notifications

Comment: With this extension, i can save notification on sqlite ?